# Unable to Draw on Bitmap at 0,0

Tags: android, bitmap, drawing

Im trying to draw a text at the coordinate 0,0 on a Bitmap using the code

```
   canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, paint);
```

but the text is drawn outside the image,the text only appears when i try some 20,25 values.Why is this? isnt this code supposed to draw text at 0,0 i had tried `(0.0f,0.0f)` no luck.

Comment: does your bitmap have any padding, margin, or such ?

Comment: @njzk2 are you referring to the imageview?

Comment: did you try to look at your design with hierarchy viewer ?

Comment: @njzk2 well, i don't know what that is iam a newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Y coordinate is for the text baseline, not the top. 
If you want the text top to be at y=0, do something like

```
FontMetrics fm = paint.getFontMetrics();
canvas.drawText(text, 0 /*x*/, 0 /*y*/ -  fm.ascent, paint);
```

Comment: Thanks.My lap had just crashed,will get back after restoring it.